# A Laravel 8 Accessor is Undefined for database table with pivot (with its own timestamps too) table, for JSON response to React Front end

Tags: php, json, laravel, mutators

I am encountering an issue on Laravel, an exception is thrown because of an "undefined" created_at column on one of the database tables (but not the pivot table). The accessor in question is returning a human friendly format for the date. The data is sent to the client as JSON. Here are the tables:

```
class Link extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $table='links';
    protected $perPage=24;

    protected $appends = [
        'human_friendly',
        'slug',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'url',
        'active',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'site_name',
        'twitter_site',
        'description',
        'locale'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
    ];
    
    public function getSlugAttribute() 
    {
        return Str::slug($this->attributes['slug']);
    }
    
    public function getHumanFriendlyAttribute()
    {
        // problem arises from here
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $table='users';
    protected $perPage=24;

    protected $appends = [];

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'active',
        'email',
        'password',
        'slug',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'active'=>'boolean',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function links()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Link::class);
    }
}
```

The pivot table also has timestamp columns (the migration schema):

```
Schema::create('link_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('link_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->primary(['link_id', 'user_id']);
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();

            $table->foreign('link_id')->references('id')->on('links')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

As you can see there is nothing out of the ordinary although I do suspect it's because the pivot table also have the timestamp columns. Has anyone else ran into this problem and shed some light on this problem?

Aside from this, the JSON is received very well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is related to the `created_at` column not being available on the `links` table, but it's being accessed in the `getHumanFriendlyAttribute` accessor of your `Link` model. The problem doesn't seem to be directly related to the pivot table's timestamps.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. **Ensure created_at Column Exists:**
   The most straightforward solution is to make sure that the `created_at` column exists in your `links` table. If it's not present and you want to use it in your accessor, you should create it in the table schema.

```php
Schema::create('links', function (Blueprint $table) {
    #This line adds created_at and updated_at columns
    $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

If you don't intend to use these columns, you can omit the `$table->timestamps()` line, and Laravel won't expect them.

2. **Customize Accessor:**
   If you don't want to add the `created_at` column to your `links` table, you can modify the `getHumanFriendlyAttribute` accessor to handle cases where the column might not exist. You can check if the column exists in the `$attributes` array before using it:

```php
public function getHumanFriendlyAttribute(){
    if (array_key_exists('created_at', $this->attributes)) {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffForHumans();
    } else {
        return 'N/A';// or any default value
    }
}
```

This way, if the `created_at` column is missing, it will return a default value or handle it as you see fit.

3. **Remove created_at Accessor:**
   If you don't actually need the `created_at` attribute in your JSON response, you can remove the `getHumanFriendlyAttribute` accessor altogether if it's not essential for your application.

Choose the option that best fits your requirements, whether it's adding the `created_at` column, customizing the accessor, or removing it based on your specific needs.

Comment: The created_at column does exist in the database (from the schema migrated), which is more irritable for me why it is undefined. I don't per se need the column in the JSON response, only the mutated form of the timestamp. But I will update the class method to prevent the exception breaking things. Any other thoughts would be welcome :)

Comment: how about using `$this->created_at` instead of `$this->attributes['created_at']` ?

Comment: The issue has since been resolved thank you :)